# The click event on the tableview don't have happen , i want to know the reason

Tags: java, android

I want a  view called view called [tableview](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) in my project from the GitHub. It is a view like data grid in the window and it can set every column has the different view, when I put a checkbox into the tableview, the click event of the item disappear, like this:

[[image]

If every column is a `TextView`, the click event is usually like this:

[image: the Textview in the tableview])

I think maybe because the checkbox consumes the click event, so the click of the item doesn't have any effort. But the click of the area doesn't within the area of the checkbox, I don't know how to deal with the problem.

When I put a checkbox into a  `RecycleView`, the item of the `RecycleView` works.

[image]

It is strange to me why the `RecycleView` can do it, but the `TableView` can't do it.

I need some guidance please.

Comment: thanks helping me edit the question, i am studing english hard now ! S:D

Answer (score 1):

Just add these properties to checkbox:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! it works !!!